# Общая сумма времени пользователя онлайн

Tags: sql, sqlite, дата

Всех приветствую!

В базе данных (SQLite) хранятся метаданные об пользовательских сессиях пользователя: когда авторизовался, когда завершил сессию, общее время в сети. Время считается в UNIX. Если с отображением первых двух значений проблем нет, то вот с общей суммой времени есть трудности - он отображает с даты 1970 (что является нормой для UNIX).

Есть ли возможность "человекопонятного" отображения общего проведенного в сети? К примеру, "всего я был онлайн: 0000-00-03 09:34:46" (3 дня, 9 часов, 34 минуты, 46 секунд).

Вот мой SQL-код:

```
SELECT m.user AS 'Пользователь',
       DATETIME(m.start_time, 'unixepoch') AS 'Дата и время авторизации',
       DATETIME(m.end_time, 'unixepoch') AS 'Дата и время завершения сеанса',
       DATETIME(SUM(s.life_time), 'unixepoch') AS 'Общее время в сети'
FROM metadata m
GROUP BY (m.user);
```

Что я получаю:
[image: SQL-вывод]

Comment: Ну если в полях `start_time/end_time` нормальные значения, то в поле `life_time` какой-то маловменяемый бред... Интервал - это не дата, а число, и конвертировать его в дату - заведомо бессмысленное действие.

Comment: @Akina Предлагаете работать с разницей непосредственно с числом? Например, переводить его в часы/минуты/секунды и тд?

Comment: Общее время УЖЕ число. Так что да - форматировать при выводе как интервал.